# How to bring a data from the web.config to the view controller?

Tags: angularjs, web-config

How do I bring data from the web.config to the view controller (xxx.controller.js)?

Comment: Need more context and maybe some code of what you've tried. But does this help? https://anthonychu.ca/post/how-to-pass-webconfig-settings-to-angularjs/

Comment: Dear Kinglish, I was looking at the information that happened to me but I could not make it work.

Comment: Thank you Kinglish! 
I was able to implement the solution you passed to me.